# Disable Download/Print/Share links in google doc viewer

Tags: google-api, google-docs

I am trying to find a solution for disabling Download/Print/Share links thru google API.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Upload your file to Google docs. Open the file and add &chrome=true at the end of the URL.
You can use Google's API to improve your application.

Thanks